# Why picker is not showing in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement this [date picker](https://github.com/pushtell/react-bootstrap-date-picker#api-reference)

But it does not display.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DatePicker from "react-bootstrap-date-picker";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    // Access ISO String and formatted values from the DOM.
    var hiddenInputElement = document.getElementById("example-datepicker");
    console.log(hiddenInputElement.value); // ISO String, ex: "2016-11-19T12:00:00.000Z"
    console.log(hiddenInputElement.getAttribute("data-formattedvalue")); // Formatted String, ex: "11/19/2016"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ddd
        <DatePicker
          id="example-datepicker"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

(also [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/9847rm734w))

Comment: What do the developer tools show you? By the way your link doesn't work, it shows me `Could not find dependency: 'create-react-class' relative to '/node_modules/react-bootstrap-date-picker/lib/index.js'`

Comment: I already added .it not work please change my link

Comment: so there's a lot going on here... where is your `value` in the state? where is you `handleChange` function? also, your `codesanbox` sample link doesn't compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using React v16, which the original react-bootstrap-date-picker [does not (yet) support](https://github.com/pushtell/react-bootstrap-date-picker/issues/143).
You can use the `react-16-bootstrap-date-picker` package instead.

See here for a very basic code example, without a state or a `componentDidUpdate` method, for simplicity's sake:

[image: Edit zrwlk00ymm]

Comment: @user944513 added a link to a modified version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @MrMister, you can install `react-16-bootstrap-date-picker`

installing the date picker will show you this warning:

```
npm WARN react-16-bootstrap-date-picker@5.1.2 requires a peer of create-react-class@^15.5.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Eventually, you'll need to install the following additional modules:

```
create-react-class
react-bootstrap
```

And your package.json file should look like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-16-bootstrap-date-picker": "^5.1.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
```